# jQuery: Click on div -> select option of a dropdown

Tags: jquery, select

I've got diffrent divs:

```
<div id="a"></div>
<div id="b"></div>
<div id="c"></div>
```

and a dropdown menu:

```
<select>
<option>x</option>
<option>y</option>
<option>z</option>
</select>
```

Is it possible, to get option x selected if I clicked on div id="a" and option y with click on id="b" and so on?

Thanks for your answers!

Comment: You don't have an "*option b*" so I'm assuming that clicking the first `<div>` (with an `id` of A) should select your `<option>` with the text of "X"? And the second `<div>` (`id="b"`) should select the second `<option>` and so on?

Comment: Yeah you're right. I edit my post.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One solution is to store the dropdown value in the div:

```
<div id="a" data-value="x">Click Me!</div>
<div id="b" data-value="y">Or Me!</div>
<div id="c" data-value="z">Or Me!</div>
```

And make sure to set the values of the dropdown:

```
<select>
    <option value="x">x</option>
    <option value="y">y</option>
    <option value="z">z</option>
</select>
```

Then you can add a click event handler:

```
$("div").on("click", function(e) {
    $("select").val($(this).data("value"));
});
```

Fiddle Here: http://jsfiddle.net/vgkz2kcj/

Edit: and if you want to simulate an actual click, you can do it using `.click()`. See an updated fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/vgkz2kcj/2/

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But can I simulate a click on this value, too?

Comment: @netThemes A click on which value? I'm not sure what you're asking.

Comment: Click on div id="a" => option value="x" should be clicked;
Click on div id="b" => option value ="y" should be clicked
...

Comment: Thanks - this really made my day. :)

Answer (score 0):

Try following:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>

<head>
<title>WisdmLabs</title>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>

<style>
#a, #b, #c{
cursor: pointer;
}
</style>
</head>

<body>

<div id="a">Click me to get X</div>
<div id="b">Click me to get Y</div>
<div id="c">Click me to get Z</div>

<select>
<option value="x">x</option>
<option value="y">y</option>
<option value="z">z</option>
</select>

<script>
$("div").click(function(){
 if(this.id == "a")
  $("select").find('option[value="x"]').prop('selected', true);
 if(this.id == "b")
  $("select").find('option[value="y"]').prop('selected', true);
 if(this.id == "c")
  $("select").find('option[value="z"]').prop('selected', true);
});
</script>

</body>

</html>
```